# Why is "1/churn rate" = average customer lifetime.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let’s assume that I have 100 customers at the beginning of Year 1. My annual churn rate is 10%. Based on the formula, my average customer lifetime would be 1/10%= 10 years right? However, if I allocate the customer loss to each year, I get a different result. As my annual churn rate is 10%, I lose 10 customers each year. Therefore, by the end of year 9, I would lose 90 customers and only have 10 customers stay, and by the end of year 10 I would have 0 customer. With this example, it suggests that if my churn rate is 10%, only the most loyal customers’ lifetime is 9 or 10 years, not the average customer lifetime is 10 years.

Comment: I'm assuming by "churn rate" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churn_rate)) you mean the proportion of customers that leave your business over a given time period, or in this case, one year. If that is the case, you should make that clear, as most people on this site aren't going to be familiar with this.

Comment: The distribution has a positive tail, so "average customer lifetime" (the mean) is not the same as "lifetime of average customer" (the median), the latter being much less than the former.  Indeed the median is $\approx\log_{9/10}(1/2)\approx 6.6$ years and only about $e^{-1}$ would remain after 10 years.

Answer (score 2):

A 10% churn rate is supposed to be interpreted as:

> "Every year, there is a 10% chance that a given customer will stop doing business with my company"

instead of:

> "Every year my company will lose exactly 10% of its customers."

With that understanding, the time $T$ for any individual customer to leave is a [geometric random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Properties) with $p = 0.10$, and so the expectation $\Bbb{E}[T] = \frac{1}{p} = 10$.

The mistake here is thinking the 10% churn rate is rigidly adhered to every year. It's kind of like claiming, "This coin is fair, so it has a 50% chance of coming up heads. Therefore, if I flip the coin 20x, I will get exactly 10 heads." That's not what that 50% chance actually means. Similarly, the 10% churn rate doesn't mean exactly $1/10$ of your customers leave every year, only that any individual customer has a $1/10$ chance of terminating their business relationship with you in a given year.

*Edit:* Even if you assume you lose exactly 10% of your customers every year, that's not 10% of your *initial* customers, that's 10% of your *current* customers. So instead of losing exactly 10 customers every year, your losses would really look like:

Year 1: 100 - 10 = 90 customers

Year 2: 90 - 9 = 81 customers

Year 3: 81 - 8.1 = 72.9 customers...

and so forth. According to this model, if you rigidly commit to losing a (possibly fractional) tenth of your customers every year, the average time to lose any particular customer *is* exactly 10 years.

Comment: Do you mean that the time between client losses can be modeled as an exponential distribution?

Comment: @AntoniParellada It seems like in the OP the clients leave independently and at discrete rather than continuous times, so it wouldn't be correct to model their departures with an exponential distribution, which is continuous-time. I guess you could model the time between client losses geometrically, as long as you tweak your geometric distribution to be supported on the nonnegative integers (including zero) rather than the positive integers.

Comment: I was trying to lend you a hand. What are the  Bernoulli trials in your geometric distribution?

Comment: @AntoniParellada I'm not sure I understand what your quibble is with my explanation, if there is one. Can you be a little more explicit?